# Can Confluent dataproc Sink Connector write directly to google cloud storage bucket

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-dataproc

I am using kafka-connect, [Confluent dataproc sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-gcp-dataproc/current/overview.html) to write data to google dataproc cluster. My dataproc cluster is configured with google cloud storage bucket. when created, dataproc sink connector writes data to dataproc's HDFS file system through datanode and data is stored in persistent disk of dataproc nodes.

*Is there any way to configure confluent dataproc sink connector to write data directly to dataproc cluster's cloud bucket, instead of HDFS file system ?*

**Solutions tried without success**

- I have tried changing the 'fs.defaultFS' url to 'gs://<bucket_name>',
  but the connector writes to HDFS file system
- I could use google cloud
  storage connector instead of dataproc sink connector but hive
  integration support is missing in cloud storage sink connector

**Dataproc sink connector configuration**

```
{
    "name": "dataproc-sink-connector",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcp.dataproc.DataprocSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "poc-input-topic",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "gcp.dataproc.projectId": "******",
    "gcp.dataproc.region": "asia-southeast1",
    "gcp.dataproc.cluster": "******-dataproc",
    "gcp.dataproc.credentials.json": "******",
    "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.gcp.dataproc.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat",
    "flush.size": "330",
    "storage.class": " io.confluent.connect.gcp.dataproc.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage",
    "topics.dir": "data",
    "logs.dir": "logs",
    "store.url": "gs://*****-dataproc-bucket/",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "hive.integration": "true",
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://*******:9083",
    "hive.database": "fnidb",
    "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD",
    "confluent.topic.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm": "https",
    "confluent.topic.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "confluent.topic.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='*****' password='*****'",
    "confluent.topic.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "confluent.topic.request.timeout.ms": "20000",
    "confluent.topic.retry.backoff.ms": "500",
    "confluent.topic.sasl.kerberos.service.name": "kafka",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "******.asia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "*****:*************",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://******.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "*****:*************",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://******.australia-southeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud",
    "hdfs.authentication.kerberos": "true",
    "connect.hdfs.principal": "hdfs/****@REALM.COM",
    "connect.hdfs.keytab": "/etc/security/keytab/hdfs.service.keytab",
    "hdfs.namenode.principal": "hdfs/****@REALM.COM",
    "kerberos.ticket.renew.period.ms": "3600000",
    "hive.conf.dir": "/etc/hive/conf"
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write to a Hive table? You can configure the Hive table storage to GCS.

Comment: Confluent has its own GCS Sink connector that you could use instead, however it doesn't integrate with Hive and you'd have to manage those partitions on your own. Otherwise, sounds like you are wanting to insert into an external hive table?